# Javascript return object properties in order of value

Tags: javascript, oop, sorting

If I have an object with the following properties/values:
{2: 4, 4: 2, 6: 3}

How can I return a list of the properties in order of their value, so I would like to return 
{4: 2, 6: 3, 2: 4 }

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Object properties are not ordered.

Comment: I think you should have you own sorting method.

Comment: I understand they are not ordered, but I have an object with these values and want to output them in the order of their value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions but they didn't work. I came across this that solved the issue:

```
function sortProperties(obj)
{
  // convert object into array
    var sortable=[];
    for(var key in obj)
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            sortable.push([key, obj[key]]); // each item is an array in format [key, value]

    // sort items by value
    sortable.sort(function(a, b)
    {
        var x=a[1],
            y=b[1];
        return x>y ? -1 : x<y ? 1 : 0;
    });
    return sortable; // array in format [ [ key1, val1 ], [ key2, val2 ], ... ]
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/umidjons/9614157